# как создать анимацию на javascript?

Tags: javascript

на днях смотрел как создать игру на джаваскрипт так скажем практиковался
и тут проблема нужно создать анимацию что бы картинка менялась на другую 
объясню все точно.Я добавил канвас елемент

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

потом начал создавать и добавлять картинки

```
var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeUp = new Image();
var pipeBottom = new Image();


bg.src = "img/bg.png";
bird.src = "img/bird.png";
fg.src = "img/fg.png";
pipeUp.src = "img/pipeUp.png";
pipeBottom.src = "img/pipeBottom.png";
```

начал их рисовать

```
 function draw() {


ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
     ctx.drawImage(fg, 0, cvs.height - fg.height);
     ctx.drawImage(bird, 10, 100);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    bird.onload = draw;
```

скажите как сделать так что бы картинка менялась после нажатия на определёную клавишу прошу с объяснением .

Comment: я бы советовал попробовать на простом js, без canvas, а как освоитесь сразу на посложнее переходить.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, переключать нужно будет клавишей с кодом 39: (стрелка вправо)

```html
<img id=myimage src="img/bird.png" />
<script>
var images = ["bird", "bg", "fg", "pipeup", "pipeBottom"];
var index = 0;
document.onkeydown = function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 39){
 index ++;
 if(index >= images.length) index = 0;
 document.getElementById("myimage").src = "img/" + images[index] + ".png";
}
}
</script>
```

Правда, тоже без canvas.